# Update Android App Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, apk

So I got a simple app with a sqli database,

the app just shows the content which is saved in the database.

So if I am correct the sqli database is saved inside the app (apk),

what I am questioning myself is if I do have repeatedly upload the app / apk if I change, delete or add something in the database.

If yes is there a way around this, to like get the data from a database without repeatedly uploading the application if data has changed.

Comment: You only have to uninstall and reinstall the app when you make a change to the database schema.

Comment: If you don't want to upload your app again and again then you can save you data in server and fetch data from server using API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you change something in the database you need to upload the apk, because the database is inside the apk.  The alternative would be to put the database on a server.  Then you would write a back end for your app in your language of choice, and this code would access the database.  You could also use a Back End As a Service.  Google BAAS to get info on the available options.

Comment: So lets say I could write a database with php my admin and call the data with my app right, then I do not have to upload it if I change to database

Comment: You can't access the database directly with your app unless you use a BAAS package -- you would need to write a program (In Java, PHP, node, etc) that runs on the server and accesses the database